# TFS charts in .net Application?

Tags: tfs, charts

I want to call TFS Charts in my .NET application which will display output in CRM Online.

Is it possible to display  visualstudion online or TFS charts outside if so please let me know how can it be achived

is there any api to access TFS charts

Answer (score 0):

There is no way currently to lied the charts out of VSO or TFS. However you have fun access to the days through the TFS object model and VSO rest API. So you can use either to build your own charts.

I would recommend the rest API as It is much more performant. The rest API will be in TFS 2015.